# MVC - Manage account. One view with two partial views and two models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Good day class!

I am working on my manage account page where the user can change his password and email.

I have a manage view where two partial views sit, change password and change email. Both of these uses two different models. The purpose of this is to have both the change password and change email on the same page.

Changing password works if the current password is correct but my problem is when I type in the incorrect current password. This gives me a InvalidOperationException:

"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'test.Models.LocalPasswordModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'test.Models.LocalEmailModel'."

Ignore the Swedish errormessages:)

This is my models:

```
public class LocalPasswordModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nuvarande lösenord måste fyllas i.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Nuvarande lösenord")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nya lösenordet måste fyllas i.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Lösenordet måste vara minst 4 tecken lång.", MinimumLength = 4)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Nya lösenordet")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Bekräfta nya lösenordet")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "De nya angivna lösenorden stämmer inte med varandra.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class LocalEmailModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nuvarande E-postadress måste fyllas i.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Nuvarande E-postadress")]
    public string OldEmail { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nya E-postadressen måste fyllas i.")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("IsUserEmailAvailable", "Account", ErrorMessage = "E-postadressen används redan. Var god skriv in en annan E-postadress.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Nya E-postadressen")]
    public string NewEmail { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Bekräfta nya E-postadressen")]
    [Compare("NewEmail", ErrorMessage = "De nya angivna E-postadresserna stämmer inte med varandra.")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
}
```

This is my views:

"Parent View":

```
@model test.Models.LocalPasswordModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hantera ditt konto";
}

<p class="message-success">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</p>

<p>Du är inloggad som <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>.</p>

<div id="Managebox1">
    @Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial")
</div>

<div id="Managebox2">
    @Html.Partial("_ChangeEmailPartial")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

"Child view, change password":

```
@model test.Models.LocalPasswordModel

<h3>Byt lösenord</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Account")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Change Password Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Byt lösenord" id="managesubmit" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

"Child view, change email":

```
@model test.Models.LocalEmailModel

<h3>Byt E-postadress</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageEmail", "Account")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Change Email Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(n => n.OldEmail)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.OldEmail)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(n => n.NewEmail)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.NewEmail)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(n => n.ConfirmEmail)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.ConfirmEmail)
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Byt E-postadress" id="managesubmit"/>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: I removed @model test.Models.LocalPasswordModel in the parent view, manage. This did not solve it. Using two partial views with two different models, shouldnt this work?

Comment: What do the method signatures of the action methods look like? You have two forms both going on the action method `Manage` on the `AccountController`, and it seems like MVC is choosing the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Html.Partial` with just a single parameter, the name of the partial view to render, it automatically passes in the main view's model, which is `LocalPasswordModel`. What you need to do is something like the following:

```
public class ManageViewModel
{
    public ManageViewModel()
    {
        LocalPassword = new LocalPasswordModel();
        LocalEmail = new LocalEmailModel();
    }

    public LocalPasswordModel LocalPassword { get; set; }
    public LocalEmailModel LocalEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your main view:

```
@model test.Models.ManageViewModel

...

<div id="Managebox1">
    @Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial", Model.LocalPassword)
</div>

<div id="Managebox2">
    @Html.Partial("_ChangeEmailPartial", Model.LocalEmail)
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I tried your code but i get a nullreferenceexception as soon as i click to the manage view:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Did you add the constructor as I indicated? You need to initialize both of the models or you'll get null reference exceptions.

Comment: Yes i did exactly as you said. And in my ChangeEmailPartial i'll use: model test.Models.LocalEmailModel, and in my ChangePasswordpartial i'll use model test.Models.LocalPasswordModel, right?

Thanks

Comment: Have I misssed anything? Thanks

Comment: I explained it more thoroughly in my other question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677514/mvc-manage-account-change-password-and-email-in-the-same-view